# How to map js to ts again

Tags: angular, typescript

I create library as described in https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries. Then I import this library   into the angular project placed in the other folder. Then in Chrome I try to debug some code of the library into the angular project, but the code of the library is shown as js-code. How can I debug  library code as typescript-code?

Comment: Привет! Are you including source-maps when building/serving your project?

Comment: Yes, in tsconfig for the library and the angular progect I set sourceMap=true and inlineSource=true.